# Multithread on Same Method in java

Tags: java, multithreading

```
package newpackage;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

class test {

    public int in = 0;

    void helper() {

        Thread t1 = new Thread(
                ()
                -> {

            add();

        }
        );

        Thread t2 = new Thread(
                ()
                -> {

            add();

        }
        );
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    void add() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
            in += i;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test a = new test();
        a.helper();
        System.out.println(a.in);
    }
}
```

What i want is to run a same method from different threads concurrently.

But the code given above doesn't give proper result .It gives output less than 1560 (780+780) .How can i achieve that ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Re "proper result", what is your expected output, and what is your observed output? Also, your method does nothing -- please post real code, code we can compile, test and modify.

Comment: "doesn't give proper result" I presume you mean it doesn't give the result you expect, because it definitely does what the Java spec says it should. What do you think it should do, what does it do instead?

Comment: @AndyTurner sorry . i did so for the sake of simplicity . now  edited .

Answer (score 1):

You have run into one of the classic problems of concurrent programs. Mutable shared state without proper synchronization. Your variable `in` is modified by both threads concurrently and moreover the `i += 1` operation is not atomic. In reality what happens is:

```
int temp = i + 1;
i = temp;
```

The problem now is that both threads run concurrently, so what can happen is this:

```
// assuming i == 3
int temp = i + 1; // Thread 1, temp == 4
int temp = i + 1; // Thread 2, temp == 4
i = temp; // Thread 2, i == 4
i = temp; // Thread 1, i == 4
```

As you can see we have incremented twice, but i has only gone up by 1. Moreover since your variable is not volatile or anything there are no visibility guarantees across threads, meaning if Thread 1 modifies the variable the JVM is not guaranteed to make that change visible to any other thread reading the variable.

To do this properly you will need to use some kind of synchronization aid, the simplest would be a `synchronized` block. However in this case that would defeat the purpose of adding things up in parallel, since the synchronization would make things run effectively in sequence, with some overhead.

If you really want to add things up in parallel, look into Java 8 Streams or the Fork-Join Framework in Java 7. Note however that doing this only pays of with a large enough dataset, since running in parallel always comes with some overhead.

Comment: thanks . got it . Then what if my add() function wouldn't work on the same object/variable . Say my add() function takes parameter of fileName and then writes to it. So if i pass two different file name to same function  from different threads ,would there be any sort of corruption ?

Comment: No, writing to separate files can be done from different threads in parallel although ultimately this would depend on the underlying file system.